# Verify List of Json Object empty

Tags: java, list

How to check a List is empty or not when it contains empty Json object.

Below is the example:

```
"data": {"parseList" : [{}]}
```

now I want to check parseList is empty or not , I tried using

```
collectionUtils.isEmpty(parseList);
```

but it is not working any help is appreciated.

Comment: how you are converting the JSON to Object array and what is collectionUtils is it from any 3rd party lib?

Comment: @Kumar have you tried if(parseList.size()!=0){true means list is not empty}else {false means list is empty}.

Comment: You have to check for `collectionUtils.isEmpty(parseList)` and `collectionUtils.isEmpty(map.keys())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `length()` method of `JSONObject` which returns the count of key-value pairs inside a JSONObject.

So you can find out if your object is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse Json using org.json and obtain JsonArray object. The length() method could be used to find the number of elements inside JsonArray.

```
String stringToParse = "";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);

JSONArray array = myjson.getJSONArray("parseList");
System.out.println(array.length());
```